# Verificar Conexão com a API em tempo real AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest

Sei que é possível verificar a existência de conexão com a internet, mas seria possível verificar se minha aplicação está conectada com a API onde ambas ficam na rede local.

Por exemplo, caso de um problema na rede e essa aplicação não consiga se comunicar com a API uma mensagem apareceria informando o usuário sobre a situação.

Quais seriam os passos para obter esse resultado?

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria 'pingar' a api em um intervalo pré estabelecido de tempo, tipo uns 10 seg.

Eu já utilizei assim.

Ai caso o ping retorne algum erro informamos o usuário.

Comment: De começo eu pensei nisso também, porém fiquei com um pouco de receio de "pesar" a aplicação. Isso poderia acontecer?

Comment: Utilize o ping e retorno com o mínimo de dados possível ex: um json com variavel status e valor 1 ou talvez apenas um retorno com 1, vai USAR pouquissimo recurso de rede e nao vai deixar nada lento